# JS/jQuery lightbox plugin with hard links and customization?

Tags: javascript, html, images, image-viewer, jquery

I am looking for a lightbox plugin to suit all my needs. I am building a photography portfolio site, and currently working on the gallery. I dont want each image to have its own site, but I do however want to have a unique link to each image where it opens in a lightbox.

I found this: https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/hash.html which I am currently using, but it does not provide "UNIQUE" hash links, as its only giving links in the form of: www.foo.com/bar/foobar.php#lg=1&slide=0. This means that whenever I add a photo to the gallery, the link is no longer relevant, since it only link based on image number.

I found also this: http://marekdedic.github.io/imagelightbox/? which provides the possibility to write a unique id for each image. This is exactly what I want with a unique link, however:

I also want the other features of the lightgallery. Download button, share button, possibility of EXIF addon etc.

Is there any other plugin like this with the functionality I want?